# Install SQL Developer mac osx 10.9.1

Tags: sql, macos

i'm trying to install Oracle's SQL Developer in my macbook pro OSX 10.9.1 but I can't understand how to do it. I download a .gz file which I unzip to get an installer but all I have is an unknown file called sqldeveloper-4.0.0.13-1.80-macosx. It is not a .dmg or something so i don't know what to do whith it.

I've read that i'm supposed to run over the extracted directory something like sh sqldeveloper.sh from the terminal but that file isn't there, just the one mentioned above.

thanks

Comment: try extracting the sqldeveloper-4.0.0.13.80-macosx.gz again and see if you can get a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extraction problem, "The Unarchiver" utility produced the unknown file, I decompressed the file download from Oracle's website with the Archive Utility and I got the installation file